# Symbok @Data annotation is imported but fields seems to not use it

Tags: php, symfony

I've created entity class Employee.php and want fields to use @Data annotation in it.

I've actually tried following instructions in https://github.com/mtarld/symbok-bundle which includes editing symbok.yaml with default configuration (there was no file so I had to create it under config/packages/). Furthermore I've inspected if composer correctly adds bundle and everything seems to be ok.

Employee.php:

```php
namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Mtarld\SymbokBundle\Annotation\Data;
use Mtarld\SymbokBundle\Annotation\ToString;

/**
 * @Data
 * @ToString
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\EmployeeRepository")
 */
class Employee
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @var int
     */
   private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @var string
     */
   private $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @var string
     */
    private $lastName;
}
```

symbok.yaml:

```
symbok:
    # Namespaces that you wanna be processed
    namespaces:
        - 'App\Entity'
        - 'App\Model'

    # Cache activation (useful to disable it when developing)
    cache: ~

    defaults:
        # If setters are fluent by default (default false)
        fluent_setters: ~

        nullable:
            # If getters and setters use/return nullable parametes/values (default false)
            getter_setter: ~

            # If constructor uses nullable parameters (default true)
            constructor: ~
```

bundles.php:

```php
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Mtarld\SymbokBundle\SymbokBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];
```

All I've got is "Unused  private field .
Moreover when I'm running:
 php bin/console doctrine:schema:update

I've got:

In AnnotationException.php line 54:

[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Data" in class App\Entity\Employee was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?

Comment: What version of symfony are you trying to use this with?

Comment: Newest one: 4.3

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the unused private field is PHPMD notice. If it's the case, just add `@SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedPrivateField)` annotation on top of the class.

For the `@Data` annotation error, have a try with 2.0 version.